# What is the difference between tag and image layer id in docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-image

According to my understanding image layer id is unique id for each layer of image and tag is something we append with the name of image for e.g username/repo:tag. example of tag is "latest" which means this one is the most recent update of the image. So image layer also did the same thing. once we update image it is updated to another layer and hence getting another unique layer id. So, why we use two identifiers tag and image layer id to differentiate between different versions of image?

Answer (score 0):

Image IDs are pseudorandom hex strings, which while unique and convenient for computers, are hard for humans to remember and use. Tags are basically nicknames that you can assign to these IDs to make them easier to use.

Also, image IDs are permanent and unchanging, while tags can be reassigned from one image to another.

Comment: so that means the purpose of both are same.

Answer (score 0):

Docker image IDs is a digest and is a computed SHA256 hash of the image configuration object, which contains the digests of the layers that contribute to the image's filesystem definition.  If you want to check the full docker image ID run the following command

```
docker images --no-trunc
```

IDs are unique. Since it's difficult to remember image IDs, it is preferable to use the image/repository name.

[Docker tags](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) enable you to ensure that anyone who pulls down your images knows exactly what they are getting. You can use the docker tag for versioning. For e.g, you can tag the different version of Ubuntu images

Ref: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-use-docker-tags-to-add-version-control-to-images/

Answer (score 0):

Image ID's are unique. An image can have multiple tags associated with it.

```
REPOSITORY                       TAG                   IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hello-world                      latest                4ab4c602aa5e        4 weeks ago         1.84kB
hello-world                      linux                 4ab4c602aa5e        4 weeks ago         1.84kB
```